# Ajax is not working in login page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am learning Ajax and trying to make a login page with php. I can't understand why my code is not working. Whenever I click on login Button, my page redirect to another page ( e.g exam.php) without checking my login function. My Codes are as follows. I will be glad if someone help me to find out the problem.

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post">
 <input name="email" type="text" id="email">
 <input name="password" type="password" id="password">
 <input type="submit" name="login" id="loginsubmit" value="Login">
</form>
   <span class="empty" style="display:none">Field must be empty..</span>
   <span class="error" style="display:none">Email or Password not matched !!!</span>
   <span class="disable" style="display:none">User Id Disabled.</span>
```

**AJAX Codes**

```
$(function(){
// For user login
$("#loginsubmit").click(function(){
    var email       = $("#email").val();
    var password    = $("#password").val();
    var dataString  = 'email='+email+'&password='+password;
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"getlogin.php",
        data:dataString,
        success: function(data){
            if ($.trim(data) == "empty") {
                $(".empty").show();
            }else if($.trim(data) == "disable") {
                $(".disable").show();
            }else if($.trim(data) == "error"){
                $(".error").show();
            } else {
                window.location = "exam.php";
                //document.write = "You shall not pass";
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

**getlogin.php**

```
$filepath = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
include_once ($filepath.'/classes/user.php');
$usr = new User();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // this values are coming from main.js
    $email    = $_POST['email'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);        
    $userlogin = $usr->userLogin($email, $password ); // function created in user.php page
}
```

**user.php**

```
$filepath = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
include_once ($filepath.'/../lib/Session.php');
include_once ($filepath.'/../lib/Database.php');
include_once ($filepath.'/../helpers/Format.php');

public function userLogin($email, $password ){
    $email      = $this->fm->validation($email);
    $password   = $this->fm->validation($password);
    $email      = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $email);
    $password   = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $password);

        if ($email == "" || $password == "" )
         {
            echo " empty";
            exit();
        } else {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'";
            $result = $this->db->select($query);
            if ($result != false) {
                $value = $result->fetch_assoc();
                if ($value['status'] == '1') {
                    echo " disable";
                    exit();
                } else {
                    Session::init();
                    Session::set("login", true);
                    Session::set("userid", $value['userid']);
                    Session::set("username", $value['username']);
                    Session::set("name", $value['name']);
                }
            } else {
                echo " error";
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check out https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/. See also [MCVE]

Comment: where is the User class definition?

Comment: $usr = new User();  added it in getlogin.php page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem is because the absence of `User` class definition, so the output of this script is fatal error and it goes directly to your `else` statement inside the ajax call.

In chrome you can check the output of your ajax request using developer tools under 'Network' tab.

Comment: $usr = new User(); added it in getlogin.php page

Comment: shouldn't the definition of the class itself be inside user.php? you are calling a `userLogin` method of class `User` without defining the class anywhere.

Comment: class User
 {
  private $db;
  private $fm;

  public function __construct()
  {
   $this->db = new Database();
   $this->fm = new Format();
  }

Comment: added it in user.php did not mention it here

Comment: can you check the result of your ajax call using chrome developer tools?

Comment: this class is defined in user.php... i did not mention here to make short of my code.

Comment: can you instead of redirecting to exam.php line use `console.log(data)` and show me the output?

Comment: aha I forgot you can't use the developer tools, use `alert(data)` instead of `console.log(data)`

Comment: Thanks...now i've figured out the porblem..i had commented out some query at the end of user.php file which contains user class.  alert(data) catches those commented out data. i removed it and now it's working.. thank you very much.

Comment: you should learn how to use developer tools in chrome, it will save you a lot of time and effort

Answer (score 0):

Change your button type from submit to button.